# What is the most effective way of finding answer to "which of these" type of questions?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program for a quiz answer-bot (for educational purposes only) and the program seems to be very accurate with direct questions ("who did that", "what happened when") but has some problems with questions which involve the answers as part of itself ("which of these").
For now, I am googling the question together with the first answer, then the second and the third and comparing total results.
This approach is still pretty inaccurate and I wanted to know if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: It's a very broad question. You should add a sample of your code and explain better the problem.

Comment: I have posted a more specific question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090934/finding-answer-to-which-of-these-questions . If you could take a look I would be grateful.